# When is the Frobenius endomorphims an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I did this problem, but now I'm left with more questions!
Suppose $f(x)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ over $GF(2)$. Prove that if $a$ is a root
of $f$ in an extension of $GF(2)$, then $f(x)=(x-a)(x-a^2)(x-a^4)$

So I let $F = \dfrac{GF(2)}{<f>}$ so $|F| =2^3$

I understand that automorphisms maps roots to roots, so I defined this automorphism

$$\phi:F\rightarrow F$$
$$\phi(x)=x^2  \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall x \in F$$

Hence $\phi(a) =a^2 ,\phi^2(a)=a^4$

But I feel that in general $GF(p^n)$ , $\phi(x) =x^p$  is maybe not an ...isomorphism? Is it, or not?

Proof? :

Clearly $\phi$ respects addition and mulptiplication.
Injection: If $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ $\rightarrow x^p-y^p=(x-y)^p = 0 \rightarrow x=y$
Domain and codomain have same cardinality, hence bijection.

Is there a flaw in this proof?

Thanks in advanced :D

Comment: I would like to nitpick the chain of equalities you use in the middle of that deduction: the two facts you were using were $x^p - y^p = 0$ and $x^p - y^p = (x-y)^p$. I've always felt it very awkward (and confusing if I didn't realize what's going on) when people mix the equalities up rather than chain them in the order they're using them. e.g. if I wanted to write them all together, I would have written $$ 0 = x^p - y^p = (x-y)^p$$ or maybe the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proof looks good!

Having another way to see the result may help your confidence in it: the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ is a cyclic group of order $p^n - 1$. In particular, its order relatively prime to $p$, and thus every nonzero element has a unique $p$-th root. (and $0$ has a unique $p$-th root too, obviously)